# Caused by:org.flywaydb.core.internal.license.FlywayEditionUpgradeRequiredException:Flyway Enterprise Edition or MySQL upgrade required: MySQL 5.5-SCDF

Tags: flyway, spring-cloud-dataflow, spring-cloud-dataflow-ui

I am working on `Spring Batch and SCDF` example. In this example, I am creating s`pring-cloud-data-flow-server` using Spring Boot code and trying to connect to the MySQL DB by looking at: [SCDF Task DB Configurations](https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-dataflow/docs/2.1.0.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#_task_database_configuration), but getting below error.

Error:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'flywayInitializer' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/flyway/FlywayAutoConfiguration$FlywayConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.flywaydb.core.internal.license.FlywayEditionUpgradeRequiredException: Flyway Enterprise Edition or MySQL upgrade required: MySQL 5.5 is no longer supported by Flyway Community Edition, but still supported by Flyway Enterprise Edition.
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1796) ~[spring-beans-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:595) ~[spring-beans-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517) ~[spring-beans-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:323) ~[spring-beans-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222) ~[spring-beans-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:321) ~[spring-beans-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202) ~[spring-beans-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:310) ~[spring-beans-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202) ~[spring-beans-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1108) ~[spring-context-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:868) ~[spring-context-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:550) ~[spring-context-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:141) ~[spring-boot-2.2.6.RELEASE.jar:2.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:747) [spring-boot-2.2.6.RELEASE.jar:2.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:397) [spring-boot-2.2.6.RELEASE.jar:2.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:315) [spring-boot-2.2.6.RELEASE.jar:2.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1226) [spring-boot-2.2.6.RELEASE.jar:2.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1215) [spring-boot-2.2.6.RELEASE.jar:2.2.6.RELEASE]
    at com.example.SpringCloudDataFlowServerApplication.main(SpringCloudDataFlowServerApplication.java:13) [classes/:na]
Caused by: org.flywaydb.core.internal.license.FlywayEditionUpgradeRequiredException: Flyway Enterprise Edition or MySQL upgrade required: MySQL 5.5 is no longer supported by Flyway Community Edition, but still supported by Flyway Enterprise Edition.
    at org.flywaydb.core.internal.database.base.Database.ensureDatabaseNotOlderThanOtherwiseRecommendUpgradeToFlywayEdition(Database.java:169) ~[flyway-core-6.0.8.jar:na]
    at org.flywaydb.core.internal.database.mysql.MySQLDatabase.ensureSupported(MySQLDatabase.java:253) ~[flyway-core-6.0.8.jar:na]
    at org.flywaydb.core.Flyway.execute(Flyway.java:495) ~[flyway-core-6.0.8.jar:na]
    at org.flywaydb.core.Flyway.migrate(Flyway.java:149) ~[flyway-core-6.0.8.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.flyway.FlywayMigrationInitializer.afterPropertiesSet(FlywayMigrationInitializer.java:65) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.2.6.RELEASE.jar:2.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1855) ~[spring-beans-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1792) ~[spring-beans-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    ... 18 common frames omitted
```

SpringCloudDataFlowServerApplication.java

```
@EnableDataFlowServer
@SpringBootApplication(exclude = { CloudFoundryDeployerAutoConfiguration.class })
public class SpringCloudDataFlowServerApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(SpringCloudDataFlowServerApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

application.properties

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=root
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=org.mariadb.jdbc.Driver

spring.cloud.dataflow.features.streams-enabled=false
```

pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.6.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-cloud-data-flow-server</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>spring-cloud-data-flow-server</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <maven-jar-plugin.version>3.1.1</maven-jar-plugin.version>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <spring-cloud-starter-dataflow-server.version>2.4.2.RELEASE</spring-cloud-starter-dataflow-server.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-dataflow-server</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-cloud-starter-dataflow-server.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>8.0.19</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Answer (score 2):

spring boot 2.2.x supplies flyway version 6. This version does not support mysql 5.5. You could try to override the flyway version to 5.2.4

```html
<dependency>
 <groupId>org.flywaydb</groupId>
 <artifactId>flyway-core</artifactId>
 <version>5.2.4</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

This restriction is no longer in place from Flyway version 10 (October 2023). We have updated Flyway so that it works with ALL supported database versions, so if you upgrade to version 10 you can access all supported versions of MySQL.

The community version of Flyway now works with All versions of MySQL.

Answer (score 0):

Refer to the latest [SCDF documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-dataflow/docs/2.11.x/reference/htmlsingle/#configuration-local-rdbms).

If you are using MySQL 5.7 or before you should add `?permitMysqlScheme` to the jdbc url.If you are using MySQL 8 or later you should add `?allowPublicKeyRetrieval=true&useSSL=false&autoReconnect=true&permitMysqlScheme` to the jdbc url.